# Is it possible to pass variables by name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am coming from CF to PHP, specifically Laravel, so I apologize for such a basic question.

I have a function in a controller :

```
public function search(
    $surveyId = 0
,   $sampleId = 0
,   $data = []
,   $dataSeg = 0
,   $returnLimit = 1000
,   $returnStartRow = 1
,   $sortOn = ""
,   $sortDir = ""
,   $previousData = []
){
   // bunch of code
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to pass in only specific variables that are needed like I can in cf?  Trying to do something like this :

```
    $myData = [
        "State" => "AZ"
    ];

    $allRecords = (new MyController)->search($surveyId=3762,$data=$myData,$sortOn="name");
```

I know this is a simple process in cf if the only three variable I need for a specific call are, in this case, the surveyId and the data array and the sortOn but I can't find the correct way to do this in Laravel (php) or even if this is a possibility at all. BTW I am using Laravel 5.7

**RESULT :** 
Based on @Nguyen's answer here is what the beginning of my controller ended up looking like, incase it is helpful to someone else :

```
public function search($params){
    // parameters that should be passed in 
    $surveyId = key_exists("surveyId", $params) ? $params['surveyId'] : 0;
    $sampleId = key_exists("sampleId", $params) ? $params['sampleId'] : 0;
    $data = key_exists("data", $params) ? $params['data'] : [];
    $dataSeg = key_exists("dataSeg", $params) ? $params['dataSeg'] : 0;
    $returnLimit = key_exists("returnLimit", $params) ? $params['returnLimit'] : 1000;
    $returnStartRow = key_exists("returnStartRow", $params) ? $params['returnStartRow'] : 1;
    $sortOn = key_exists("sortOn", $params) ? $params['sortOn'] : "";
    $sortDir = key_exists("sortDir", $params) ? $params['sortDir'] : "";
    $previousData = key_exists("previousData", $params) ? $params['previousData'] : [];
    // end parameters that should be passed in 

     ## logic code 
}
```

Comment: just make a try, you can see the results on your hand

Comment: PHP does not support pass by name. You will need to give all intermediate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass parameter by name. If you want, change parameter to array like this:

```
public function search($param){
  // your code here
}
$allRecords = (new MyController)->search(["surveyId"=>3762,"data"=>$myData,"sortOn"=>"name"]);
```